Large drain opening found in basement slab. Best way to tile around it?
I was tearing up a wooden platform the previous owners had in our laundry room because I'm going to tile.
I figured I'd find a drain in the slab underneath but not something this big. It's probably 12 inch x 12 inch roughly, maybe 10 inch deep and then collapses down to a 3-4 inch drain hole.
Why is this hole so big? I'm wondering what I should do to cover this before tiling. Should I put a big metal grate over it or reduce the size of the opening with concrete?
It appears this drain used to be used for a utility sink and we were hoping to get a new sink and get it plumbed down this drain. Thanks for any help!
Nick


we were hoping to get a new sink and get it plumbed down this drain ... where does the drain lead? ... what do you feel when you touch inside the 3-4 inch drain hole?

That may just drain to soil. I would reserve it for spills and put in real drainage for laundry or any other deliberate water flow. (It probably doesn't have a trap, so it probably isn't draining to sewer or septic.) Personally, I'd consider at least putting a grate over it; if water can get out, critters can get in.
